# Kill Activity on Dialog Back Button

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have a dialog that pops up in my activity.  I want it to finish the entire activity when the back button is pressed on the dialog.  How would I do this?

Comment: Posting a bit of code may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set the onCancelListener for the dialog and call finish() when its called.

```
setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
      removeDialog(DIALOG_ALERT);
      finish();
    }
})
```